# LINQ to JSON - Setup list from different arrays

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, json.net, linq-to-json

I have a polymorphic json string.  Here's what it looks like:

```
{
    "Product" : {
        "Context" : {
            "IssuerDetails" : {
                "Issuer" : {
                    "@clientCode" : "BMTEST-CA",
                    "@companyName" : "zTest BM Company, Inc",
                    "@companyId" : "1",
                    "IssuerChanges" : [{
                            "@type" : "Book Value",
                            "@previous" : "$9.06",
                            "@current" : "$55.34"
                        }, {
                            "@type" : "Price Target",
                            "@previous" : "$50.00",
                            "@current" : "$199.00"
                        }, {
                            "@type" : "EPS",
                            "@previous" : "2.10",
                            "@current" : "2.09",
                            "@period" : "5",
                            "@year" : "2017"
                        }, {
                            "@type" : "Income Tax",
                            "@previous" : "56",
                            "@current" : "55",
                            "@period" : "5",
                            "@year" : "2015"
                        }
                    ],
                    "SecurityDetails" : {
                        "Security" : {
                            "@primaryIndicator" : "Yes",
                            "Clusters" : [{
                                    "@name" : "Company Data",
                                    "@rank" : "2",
                                    "FinancialValue" : [{
                                            "@financialsType" : "Dividend",
                                            "CurrentValue" : {
                                                "@displayValue" : "$5.02",
                                            }
                                        }, {
                                            "@financialsType" : "Book Value",
                                            "CurrentValue" : {
                                                "@displayValue" : "$55.34",
                                            },
                                            "PreviousValue" : {
                                                "@displayValue" : "$9.06",
                                                "@type" : "INCREASE",
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    "@rank" : "1",
                                    "@name" : "AAPL & Market Data",
                                    "FinancialValue" : [{
                                            "@financialsType" : "Rating",
                                            "@shortCode" : "Mkt",
                                            "CurrentValue" : {
                                                "@displayValue" : "Market Perform",
                                            }
                                        }, {
                                            "@financialsType" : "Rating Qualifier",
                                            "CurrentValue" : {
                                                "@displayValue" : "Speculative",
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the following extension class:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<JObject> ObjectsOrSelf(this JToken root)
    {
        if (root is JObject)
            yield return (JObject)root;
        else if (root is JContainer)
            foreach (var item in ((JContainer)root).Children())
                foreach (var child in item.ObjectsOrSelf())
                    yield return child;
        else
            yield break;
    }
}
```

Based on that, here's my query:

```
JObject feed = JObject.Parse(jsonText);

var compInfo = from issuer in feed.SelectTokens("Product.Context.IssuerDetails.Issuer").SelectMany(i => i.ObjectsOrSelf())
       let issuerChanges = issuer.SelectTokens("IssuerChanges").SelectMany(s => s.ObjectsOrSelf())
       where issuerChanges != null 
       let finValues = issuer.SelectTokens("SecurityDetails.Security.Clusters").SelectMany(s => s.ObjectsOrSelf())
       where finValues != null
       select new
        {
           Id = (int)issuer["@companyId"], 
           BMOTicker = (string)issuer["@clientCode"],
           CompName = (string)issuer["@companyName"],
           ChngsType = issuerChanges.Select(c => (string)c["@type"]),
           PrevChng = issuerChanges.Select(c => (string)c["@previous"]),
           CurrChng = issuerChanges.Select(c => (string)c["@current"]),
           Period = issuerChanges.Select(c => (string)c["@period"]),
           Year = issuerChanges.Select(c => (string)c["@year"]),
           FinValueName = finValues.Select(c => (string)c["@financialsType"])
    };
```

When I tried the query, I don't get an error but get the following (from LinqPad):
[image]

The end result should look like this (simulated in Excel):
[image]

Any idea how can I get the end result?

Comment: Please fix the image links or post the actual and expected result as text

Comment: Sorry about that.  It was a formatting issue that prevented showing the images.

Comment: What is the relationship between the FinType/Value pairs and the rest of the data in your desired/simulated result?  I don't see why the "Dividend" FinType goes with the "Book Value" ChgsType, and the "BookValue" FinType goes with the "Price Target" ChgsType, etc.

Comment: There isn't a relationship between them.  Does that mean that this isn't possible?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it seems strange/unintuitive to have unrelated data in the same "table".

Answer (score 1):

**First**, you want to get rid of those `ChngsType`, `PrevChng`, etc. nested tables in the `compInfo`. You may use `SelectMany()` (fluent syntax) or recurrent `from` keywords (query syntax) like in this example:

```
var compInfoTest1 =
    from issuer in feed.SelectTokens("Product.Context.IssuerDetails.Issuer")
    from change in issuer["IssuerChanges"]
    select new { Company = issuer["@companyName"], Type = change["@type"] };
```

You can see the `compInfoTest1` contains a flat Company-Type table:

```
{ Company = {zTest BM Company, Inc}, Type = {Book Value} }
{ Company = {zTest BM Company, Inc}, Type = {Price Target} }
{ Company = {zTest BM Company, Inc}, Type = {EPS} }
{ Company = {zTest BM Company, Inc}, Type = {Income Tax} }
```

Please note the `ObjectsOrSelf()` extension method is not required to do this.

**Second**, the `ObjectsOrSelf()` fails on the double nested structure of `SecurityDetails` (object->array->object->array->object -- it stops on the second object level thus failing to reach `@financialsType`). To deal with this, you need to use the same flattening technics repeating `from` for the every next inner level:

```
var compInfoTest2 =
    from issuer in feed.SelectTokens("Product.Context.IssuerDetails.Issuer")
    from cluster in issuer["SecurityDetails"]["Security"]["Clusters"]
    from finVal in cluster["FinancialValue"]
    select new { Company = issuer["@companyName"], FinType = finVal["@financialsType"] };
```

Here is the query result:

```
{ Company = {zTest BM Company, Inc}, FinType = {Dividend} }
{ Company = {zTest BM Company, Inc}, FinType = {Book Value} }
{ Company = {zTest BM Company, Inc}, FinType = {Rating} }
{ Company = {zTest BM Company, Inc}, FinType = {Rating Qualifier} }
```

**Third**, since there is no relationship between the FinType/Value pairs and the rest of the data, you can't write any condition to match items in the `change` and `finVal` sets. Instead, you may use [`Enumerable.Zip()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) to glue the "corresponding" items.

So the **final query** is:

```
var compInfo =
    from issuer in feed.SelectTokens("Product.Context.IssuerDetails.Issuer")
    let finValues = (
        from cluster in issuer["SecurityDetails"]["Security"]["Clusters"]
        from finVal in cluster["FinancialValue"]
        select new {
            FinValueName = (string)finVal["@financialsType"],
            Value = (string)finVal["CurrentValue"]["@displayValue"],
        }
    )
    from changesAndFinValues in issuer["IssuerChanges"].Zip(finValues, (c,f) => new {
            ChngsType = (string)c["@type"],
            PrevChng = (string)c["@previous"],
            CurrChng = (string)c["@current"],
            Period = (string)c["@period"],
            Year = (string)c["@year"],
            f.FinValueName,
            f.Value
    })
    select new
    {
        Id = (int)issuer["@companyId"],
        BMOTicker = (string)issuer["@clientCode"],
        CompName = (string)issuer["@companyName"],
        changesAndFinValues.ChngsType,
        changesAndFinValues.PrevChng,
        changesAndFinValues.CurrChng,
        changesAndFinValues.Period,
        changesAndFinValues.Year,
        changesAndFinValues.FinValueName,
        changesAndFinValues.Value,
    };
```

It produces the following result on your sample data:

```
{ Id = 1, BMOTicker = "BMTEST-CA", CompName = "zTest BM Company, Inc", ChngsType = "Book Value", PrevChng = "$9.06", CurrChng = "$55.34", Period = null, Year = null, FinValueName = "Dividend", Value = "$5.02" }
{ Id = 1, BMOTicker = "BMTEST-CA", CompName = "zTest BM Company, Inc", ChngsType = "Price Target", PrevChng = "$50.00", CurrChng = "$199.00", Period = null, Year = null, FinValueName = "Book Value", Value = "$55.34" }
{ Id = 1, BMOTicker = "BMTEST-CA", CompName = "zTest BM Company, Inc", ChngsType = "EPS", PrevChng = "2.10", CurrChng = "2.09", Period = "5", Year = "2017", FinValueName = "Rating", Value = "Market Perform" }
{ Id = 1, BMOTicker = "BMTEST-CA", CompName = "zTest BM Company, Inc", ChngsType = "Income Tax", PrevChng = "56", CurrChng = "55", Period = "5", Year = "2015", FinValueName = "Rating Qualifier", Value = "Speculative" }
```